# Convert org.json.JSONArray to org.json.simple.JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I have a library return `org.json.JSONArray` and it needs to be converted to `org.json.simple.JSONArray`.

The web server that I use has an interface that returns `org.json.simple.JSONArray` and therefore I need to convert `org.json.JSON array` to it.

I also tried converting the response to `org.json.JSONArray` but the web server based on Jersey is not able to convert it into a HTTP response.

Comment: Can you provide the code how you tried to convert?

Comment: @swinkler solved it in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to make the library (A Unirest wrapper) that returns `org.json.JSONArray` return in the `org.json.simple.JSONArray` form. Which solved the issue.

```
    Unirest.setTimeouts(1000000,1000000);
    HttpResponse<String> jsonResponse = Unirest.post(host)
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .body(String.format("{\"queryType\":\"%s\", \"query\":\"%s\"}", "SQL",
                    query))
            .asString();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    String json = jsonResponse.getBody();
    return (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
```